# how to reshape or melt a data with certain columns

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(sample = c("partB", "partB", "partB", "partB", 
"partB", "partB", "partB", "partB", "partB", "partB", "partB"
), class = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "D", "A", "B", "B", 
"B"), Link.to.data = c("data1", "data2", "data3", "data4", "data5", 
"data6", "data7", "data8", "data9", "data10", "data11"), ID = c(8019L, 
8019L, 8019L, 1001319L, 8019L, 115L, 1000486L, 8019L, 1001319L, 
1001319L, 1001319L), name4 = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L), name1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), name33 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    name = c(2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), name5 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), name9 = c(0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

I am trying to reshape it and remove some of the columns that I do not need. So, I don't need **sample, link.to.data, ID**
and I want to reshape it as class being in one long column, names is the column name of the values and the value.

I tried the following but gives error:

```
df %>% gather(class, names, value, -c(sample, link.to.data, ID))
```

Comment: `df %>% gather(class, names, -c(sample, Link.to.data, ID))`

Comment: @Onyambu
where is the value? it still have the column sample ....

Comment: The subtraction is not removal of the columns but rather treating them as id columns. Was responding to the error

Comment: `df %>%
  select(-c(sample, Link.to.data, ID))%>%
  pivot_longer(-class)`